# Is there a reason why this django form isn't valid?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

My form is valid only when I use `{{ post_form }}` without specifying the field, I know this because when I tried it I was able to save it to the data base, so I think I'm doing something wrong in my template.

By the way, none of these fields are required so I believe they should be able to go empty in the database... right?

This is the html form:

```
<section id="newpost-form">
    <form action="{% url 'newpost' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="id_title">Title</label>
        {{ post_form.title }}
        <label for="id_image">Thumbnail</label>
        {{ post_form.image }}
        {{ post_form.content }}
        {{ post_form.media }}      // this one is for a ckeditor rich text area called content
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

this is forms.py

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['image', 'title', 'content', 'status', 'author',]
```

I would like not to show the fields 'status' and 'author' because I'm handling them in the views.py after the `is_valid()`:

and my views.py in case it is relevant:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_form = NewPost(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if post_form.is_valid():
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to exclude the fields from the model form, and in your template, `{{post_form.as_p}}`, and define attributes in your forms.py fields

For example:

form.html:

```
<section id="newpost-form">
    <form action="{% url 'newpost' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ post_form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

forms.py:

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['image', 'title', 'content']

        labels = {'image': ('Image:'),'title': ('Title:'),'content': ('Content:')}

        widgets = {
            'image': forms.TextInput***imagefield or whichever field type used***(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': ''}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': ''}),
            'content': forms.TextArea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': ''}),
```

Answer (score 0):

if not don't need autor and status then remove it from your fields

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields= ['image', 'title', 'content',]
```